# UIViewController with no Xib showing blank when using pushViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have subclassed UIViewController like so:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController
```

I dont have a xib file for the controller, instead I would just like to use a blank UIView and I will layout elements programmatically on that. The problem arrises when I try and push this view controller.

```
MyClass * thing = [[ImageGallery alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thing animated:YES];
```

A new title bar is animated in, but there is no view, its see through, so I end up seeing a static background I set on my main "window/view". How should I properly subclass a UIViewController without a xib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have described is correct behaviour so far.

You will want to override the `-(void)loadView` method, and after the `[super loadView];` call, you can set your background colour and begin to place the objects in programatically, that you desire.

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was set the color. Still new to objective-c, but getting there :)